# How is the work done by rotational dry friction distributed over the surface?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, continuum-mechanics

I stumbled upon the phenomena of pushing a door without closing it and it came back to me a little. I suppose it could be explained by pressure increasing in the other room for a moment or the doors being not perfectly straight. However I am interested in how the door comes to a stop.

There is air resistance, but what I was a bit stumped by was the friction of hinges. I know that the friction must do work to reduce the kinetic energy of the door to $0$. The formula for work is $A = Fs\cos{\alpha}$, but there is less force applied where the hinge is farther from axis of rotation, since it is easier to move it there. Or maybe, since it must move faster, the force is equal there? The kinetic friction is the same everywhere $F_{friction}=\mu_{kinetic}F_{normal}$, but the continuum mechanics of normal force distribution and the entire disk surface moving is confusing to me. Here is an illustration I made:
[image]

The bottom cylinder is static and the top one is rotating about the axis of rotation. The blue area is where the friction happens.

I guess what I want to know is how is the work done by friction distributed in area? Does every bit of area do the same work to stop the hinge?

Answer (score 0):

The force of friction is proportional to the pressure squeezing the surfaces together. For a simple example, you might assume uniform pressure over the surface.

$W = Fd$, so you are interested in how far each small patch of moving surface slides. A patch close to the axis doesn't slide as far as one farther out. You might think about thin concentric rings.

If you add up a lot of small patches, you turn the sum to an integral.

Answer (score 0):

@mmesser314 made a useful simplification, that the pressure is uniform over the surface. Than I specified that I want the work of friction after one rotation, and to do that I need to find the average circumference of all the circles. Since the $C = 2\pi R$, the function grows lineary, then the average radius in the interval $[0;R]$ will be $\frac{R}{2}$.

The friction force is $F_{friction}=\mu mg$, it works for one cycle and the work is $A=Fs$, putting everything together:

$A = \mu mg \pi R$

So rotating for one cycle is the same as pushing it for a distance of $\pi R$, which I think is interesting.